# what is the purpose of safe_string_cmp?

Tags: werkzeug

New to Flask and was going through a course that describes how to make a REST API.

Author of the course suggested using [safe_str_cmp](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/utils/#werkzeug.security.safe_str_cmp) from werkzeug.security in the authentication chapter.

I'd appreciate if someone could help understand what is the purpose of that function and when/why it should be used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The obvious algorithm to test for string equality is something like this:

```py
def strings_equal(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[i] != s2[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

However, there is a subtle problem with using this algorithm to compare password hashes. The `return` from inside the loop makes the algorithm faster when the two strings have different characters near the beginning, and slower when they have the same characters near the beginning.

This makes the comparison vulnerable to a [timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack); by trying a password with a known hash and measuring the average time it takes for the password to be rejected, it is possible for the attacker to statistically determine how many of the same characters there are at the beginnings of both hashes. By trying a sequence of different hashes to successively discover one or two bytes of the real password hash at a time, the attacker can deduce a large portion of it, and then attempt to crack it locally.

The secure string comparison algorithm might look something like this:

```py
# warning: example only! this hasn't been proven secure!
# don't use in real code!

def strings_equal(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    result = True
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        # use & for non-short-circuiting
        result = result & (s1[i] == s2[i])
    return result
```

Since all password hashes using the same hashing algorithm should have the same length, this comparison ideally should always take the same amount of time to compare two hashes, preventing a timing attack.
More generally, you should use a secure string comparison function any time you are comparing user input with any secret string.

Comment: If you get here from Jose Salvatierra's REST API course please notice – there is no `safe_str_cmp` function `form werkzeug.security` anymore in modern Werkzeug (2.2.0+) versions.